# React Native grid calendar that looks like Google Calendar's Month view

Tags: react-native, calendar, react-native-calendars

I want to add grid calendars to my React Native application, which should look like the Month view in Google Calendar (the left image). I have searched for the libraries and found [React Native Calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) but as far as I can see, it can only give me the type of calendar that looks like the one on the right image. Is there any trick for [React Native Calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars) to make a grid calendar or is there any React Native library that supports making grid calendars?

[image: Google Calendar's Month view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who was wondering the same thing, you can implement a grid calendar with a `FlatList`, which is very efficient in loading dates. Moreover, you can customize your own calendar (add notes/tasks to date, set deadlines for tasks, ...) easily with `FlatList`'s features.

If you are not familiar with `FlatList` yet, more information can be read at [FlatList documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)